# How to have some textviews in a row in a ListView? Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have a ListActivity where I have some items sorted by datetime.
I have 3 textviews. Here what I've done:

[image: layout]

Here is the code for the layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bpSysHolder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        android:text="TextView" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bpDiaHolder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bpDtHolder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

For calling them from my list activity i use:

```
        String[] from = new String[] { BpDAO.bp_SYS, BpDAO.bp_DIA, BpDAO.bp_DT };
    int[] target = new int[] { R.id.bpSysHolder, R.id.bpDiaHolder,
            R.id.bpDtHolder };
    dbAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.history_bp, bpList,
            from, target);
    setListAdapter(dbAdapter);
```

Now it is like this:

```
---120952012-09-20 15:05      ---
---145902012-09-20 10:44      ---
---145952012-09-20 10:42      ---
             ...
---14595 2012-09-20 10:42     ---
---------------------------------
```

How to have space between them and some little space up and down of the row so to be easier to touch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this also in same layout.

```
  Change android:orientation="vertical" > to android:orientation="horizontal"
```

and define use the property "Android:layout_weight" for text-view to aline according to your reqirement.

Answer (score 1):

Use this on the linear layout to have all in one line

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

On the picture you already have a title on the action bar, if you want on the list you can add a header to the list

Answer (score 1):

you are setting the orientation as vertical:

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

remove it, and you should get the textview horizzontal